# How to specify top_terms_N rewrite using Nest SDK for Elastic?

Tags: elasticsearch, console, kibana, nest

Elastic version 5.2
I have this query in elastic DSL.

```
POST my-index/_search
{
  "query": {
    "wildcard": {
      "Author": {
        "value": "*joe*",
        "rewrite": "top_terms_15"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

I want to write the same query using Nest SDK.

```
    private Nest.WildcardQuery CreateQuery()
    {
        Nest.WildcardQuery query = new Nest.WildcardQuery();
        query.Field = "Author";
        query.Value = "*joe*";           

        query.Rewrite = Nest.RewriteMultiTerm.TopTermsN;
        //Now how to specify a value for N ? 

        return query;
    }
```

How can I specify a value for N ? (when using Nest.RewriteMultiTerm.TopTermsN)

Elastic version 5.2.1
Kibana version 5.2.1
Nest version 5.2.0

Answer (score 0):

This is a bug in Elastic SDK, and according to Elastic folks, this would be fixed in the next 5.x release.

Full details can be found on the elastic forum.

https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-specify-top-terms-n-rewrite-using-nest-sdk/77743/3

According to that, there is a work around for this issue until a fix is available.

**Work around** 
Use the low client exposed on NEST.

```
var response = client.LowLevel.Search<SearchResponse<object>>("my-index",   
@"{
    ""query"": {
        ""wildcard"": {
            ""Author"": {
                ""value"": ""*joe*"",
                ""rewrite"": ""top_terms_15""
            }
        }
    }
}");

// a search response that you would be returned from a NEST search query
var nestResponse = response.Body;
```